# How to generate hashkey using multiple columns in oracle? Could you please give me an example?

Tags: oracle, hash, key

How to generate hash key using multiple columns in oracle? Could  you please give me an example?

Comment: have you tried anything or searched on SO yet?

Comment: Please can you be more specific as well. Do you just mean an index on multiple database columns or are you talking about some other data structure?

Comment: There are a few examples: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1036967
 Anyway probably you have to concatenate your fields with ||.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what you want a hash for, you might use ORA_HASH:

```
SELECT ORA_HASH(name || '~' || surname || '~' || position) FROM emp;
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions097.htm

Or you might use DBMS_CRYPTO.hash:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_crypto.htm#i1002022